# Avoid warning about undefined attribute in a StringTemplate rule

Tags: stringtemplate

In a StringTemplate rule I need to check if a certain attribute is available and act upon the outcome:

```
RuleSempredFunction(r, actions) ::= <<
bool <if (parser)><parser.name><else><lexer.name><endif>::<r.name>Sempred(Ref\<<r.ctxType>\> _localctx, int predicateIndex) {
...
>>
```

As you can see the parser attribute is not in the parameter list, which is probably why I get the warning:

> context [/LexerFile /Lexer /RuleSempredFunction] 2:10 attribute parser
>   isn't defined

Otherwise the rule works exactly like intended (it's called from /LexerFile /Lexer and /ParserFile /Parser, so once `parser` is defined and once `lexer` - from the calling rules). I just would like to get rid of the warning. Any idea?